# How to display the comment form using a shortcode while removing the default comment form below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I already have the comments shown using the short code using the [wpdiscuz_comments] but it also appears below [default].

```
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode() {
    $html = "";
    if (file_exists(ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php")) {
        ob_start();
        include_once ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php";
        $html = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode("wpdiscuz_comments", "my_wpdiscuz_shortcode");
```

my goal is to remove the comments below and use the shortcode for the comments. Thank you guys.

Comment: Look here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301994/how-to-remove-wordpress-default-comment-system

Comment: @HowardE I tried it but it also hides/removes my other comment form.